# Tkinter Python GUI Issues

Tags: python, user-interface, input, tkinter, text-files

Below is my code, it runs but I'm not sure how to get the "Run text" button to prompt me to open text file in new window, currently a new window appears with a "Quit" button, nothing else.

```
import tkFileDialog
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import logging

 logging.basicConfig(filename= "log_file.txt", filemode = "w", level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

logging.warning('is when this event was logged.')

class HomeScreen:
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
    self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Run Text', width = 25, command = self.new_window)
    self.button1.pack()
    self.frame.pack()

def openFile(self):
    openfile = tkFileDialog.askopenfile().read()
    text= open(openfile, 'r').read()
    T.insert(1.0, openfile)
    T = Text(height=10, width=100)
    T.pack()
    T.insert(END, "Select file to input")
    B = Button(root, text="Open", command=openFile)
    B.pack()
    mainloop()
    return

def new_window(self):
    self.newWindow = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
    self.app = Quit(self.newWindow)

class Quit:
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)
    self.quitButton = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Quit', width = 25, command = self.close_windows)
    self.quitButton.pack()
    self.frame.pack()
def close_windows(self):
    self.master.destroy()

def main(): 
root = tk.Tk()
app = HomeScreen(root)
app = Quit(root)
root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

I'm sure my code is very messy as I'm just a beginner, some parts may not be needed, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your intendation is not correct

Comment: use `self.openFile()` in `new_window()` before you create `newWindow` or move `self.openFile()` into `Quit` class and use it in `Quit.__init__` if you need this text file in `Quit` window.

Comment: btw: program needs only one `mainloop`

Answer (score 2):

I've simplified your code a bit, but I've also enhanced it a little. I use `askopenfilename` rather than `askopenfile`, so we can get the file name and display it in the titlebar of each Toplevel window containing a Text widget.

```
import tkFileDialog
import Tkinter as tk

class HomeScreen:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        frame = tk.Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        button = tk.Button(frame, text='Show Text', width=25, command=self.open_file)
        button.pack()
        button = tk.Button(frame, text='Quit', width=25, command=master.destroy)
        button.pack()
        master.mainloop()

    def open_file(self):
        filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
        if not filename:
            #User cancelled
            return
        with open(filename) as f:
            filedata = f.read()

        window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        window.title(filename)
        text = tk.Text(window, height=10, width=100)
        text.pack()
        text.insert(1.0, filedata)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    HomeScreen(root)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

To display the text file one word at a time you can replace the `open_file` method with the version below. You'll also need to add the `show_word` method. I'm not claiming that this is the best way to achieve this effect, but at least it works. :)

```
def show_word(self, word):
    self.text.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    self.text.insert(tk.END, word)

def open_file(self):
    filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
    if not filename:
        #User cancelled
        return
    with open(filename) as f:
        filedata = f.read()

    words = filedata.split()

    window = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
    window.title(filename)
    self.text = text = tk.Text(window, height=10, width=100)
    text.pack()

    delta = 1000    #in millseconds
    delay = 0
    for word in words:
        window.after(delay, lambda word=word: self.show_word(word))
        #print word
        delay += delta
```

Comment: thanks, this has helped me understand it more! In regards to inputing the text from the text file I have been playing around as I would like it to appear one word at a time then dissappear, i've been using:           text_file = open ("input_text.txt", "r")
for word in text_file.read().split(" "):
            print(word)
text_file.close() is their a way to integrate that into the opening of the file?

Comment: Ok. That should really be a new question, but I'll add some more code to my existing answer. BTW, if my answer has helped you. please consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that `"Run text"`  open's a file dialog change called method:

```
self.button1 = tk.Button(self.frame, text = 'Run Text', width = 25, command = self.openFile)
```