# Tkinter: How to make characters appear on text widget with a time delay?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def write_text(widget, message, enter_number, slow_type=True):
    widget.config(state="normal")
    if slow_type:
        if len(message) > 0:
            widget.insert("insert", message[0])
        if len(message) > 1:
            widget.after(100, UI.write_text, widget, message[1:], 0)
    else:
        widget.insert("insert", message)

    for i in range(enter_number):
        widget.insert("insert", "\n")

    widget.config(state="disabled")
    widget.see("end")
```

This is my code to write each characters show up in time delay

But I have a problem:

If I call this method like this (I have a widget named `text1`).

```
write_text(text1, ">>>Invalid Input", 1)
write_text(text1, ">>>Try Again...", 2)
```

Messages blend together something like this `>>>>>>ITnrvya lAigda iInn.p.u.t`.

**I want it to type messages when typing the previous message is over.**

What can I do?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English...

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34312090/4014959). It displays the text one word at a time, but you may be able to adapt it. However, to do this so it properly handle texts from multiple sources you may need to use a queue. Get the sources to send their texts to the queue, and then retrieve them from the queue to display them.

Comment: If you are using a Text widget (you didn't say), then you have to tell it where to  insert, usually it is at the end.  Note also that if the length is greater than 1 it will also be greater than zero so both will happen.  You may want an elif, i.e. if length > 1...elif length > 0  Text widget docs http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something runnable that does what I think you want. The "blended" output you're getting was because the second call you have to `write_text()` occurs before all the (delayed) processing of the first one has completed, so the text widget effectively gets updates by two separate callback processes.

The code below avoids this issue by putting the characters of the string (and what line they go on) in a `Queue` which allow them to be retrieved in the same order that they were added.

```
DELAY = 100  # ms between widget updates

def update_widget(widget):
    try:
        line_number, text = widget._text_queue.get_nowait()
    except queue.Empty:
        return  # Nothing further to do.

    widget.insert('%s.end' % line_number, text)

    if widget._text_queue.qsize():  # Anything more to process?
        widget.after(DELAY, update_widget, widget)

def write_text(widget, message, line_number, slow_type=True):
    if not slow_type:
        widget.insert('%s.0' % line_number, message)
    else:
        for ch in message:  # Add each character of message to queue.
            widget._text_queue.put((line_number, ch))

        update_widget(widget)  # Start (or continue) update processing.

def add_text(widget):
    widget.delete('1.0', tk.END)  # Delete widget's current contents.

    # Note: Tkinter always adds a newline at the very end of text widgets, so
    #    we need one less newline. This makes it possible to insert text onto
    #    any possible line of the widget -- which could fail if it was empty.
    widget.insert('1.0', (widget['height']-1) * '\n')  # Init with blank lines.
    write_text(widget, ">>>Invalid Input", 1)
    write_text(widget, ">>>Try Again...", 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    text1 = tk.Text(root, width=40, height=3, bg='skyblue')
    text1._text_queue = queue.Queue()  # Add a Queue to it for delayed updates.
    text1.grid()
    button = tk.Button(root, text='Run Test', command=lambda w=text1: add_text(w))
    button.grid()
    root.mainloop()
```