# Sequentially updating tkinter canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

The following call is activated upon a button press.

```
def ON():
  print("System Initiated")
  var.set("System Initiated")
  AC1 = circuitD.create_oval(375,155,400,180, fill= 'green')
  DCM = circuitD.create_oval(375,425,400,450, fill= 'green')
  DC2 = circuitD.create_oval(367,513,392,538, fill= 'green')
  DC1 = circuitD.create_oval(313,513,338,538, fill= 'green')
  DC3 = circuitD.create_oval(423,513,448,538, fill= 'green')
  DC4 = circuitD.create_oval(477,513,502,538, fill= 'green')
```

It simply draws 6 green circles in different areas of the canvas. 
I would like to draw them in sequence, with a one second delay. I've tried using the `time.sleep(seconds)` snippet between each line.

```
def ON():
  print("System Initiated")
  var.set("System Initiated")
  AC1 = circuitD.create_oval(375,155,400,180, fill= 'green')
  time.sleep(seconds)
  DCM = circuitD.create_oval(375,425,400,450, fill= 'green')
  time.sleep(seconds)
  DC2 = circuitD.create_oval(367,513,392,538, fill= 'green')
  time.sleep(seconds)
  DC1 = circuitD.create_oval(313,513,338,538, fill= 'green')
  time.sleep(seconds)
  DC3 = circuitD.create_oval(423,513,448,538, fill= 'green')
  time.sleep(seconds)
  DC4 = circuitD.create_oval(477,513,502,538, fill= 'green')
```

The sleep function delays the entire drawing sequence for the set amount of time, and then proceeds to draw all 6 circles at one time. It seems as though the sleep function only properly delays the shell outputs.

My questions is, is there a way to delay the circles from appearing on the canvas? Or is there a way to live update the canvas after each `time.sleep(seconds)`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's generally _not_ a good idea to use `time.sleep` with a GUI, as you've discovered. Take a look at Tkinter's `.after` method. There's a simple example at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34313194/4014959). Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44372709/4014959

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the whole program locking up during the sequence, then you can add a `circuitD.update()` after the sleep.

Otherwise, you'll have to use an `after` call, but that will screw with your ability to keep references to the created objects. What are you using those references for?

I could show an example if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: 'circuitD.update()'  works fine for me. Its a startup process so locking up the program is what should be happening. Thank you.